# Solve $(3-4i)^3z^3=1$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I totally stuck in solving the equation $$(3-4i)^3z^3=1$$ My idea is isolate $z^3$ and then try to solve it but I don't know how to proceed. I just started studying complex numbers so I have to do a lot of exercise. Can somebody help me (keeping in mind that I've just started doing this kind of equation)? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$z^3=\frac1{(3-4i)^3}=\left(\frac1{3-4i}\right)^3=\left(\frac{3+4i}{(3-4i)(3+4i)}\right)^3$$

Hope you can take it from here

Comment: If he drops the cube on both sides to get a solution for $z$, doesn't he still need to consider the additional solutions $z\omega$ and $z\omega^2$, where $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ are the two primitive complex cube roots of unity?

Comment: @Deepak, He will reach at the same destination

Comment: Meaning he can neglect that part? Or that he should realise that he still needs to multiply by those to get the complete solution set (but you left it unsaid)? Just clarifying.

Comment: @Deepak, How can he neglect that? He  must multiply

Comment: Ah, OK. So you just left it for him to figure out. Thanks. Personally, I would just have taken cube roots of both sides, with the RHS becoming $1, \omega, \omega^2$ and then proceeding from there.

Comment: I can solve it now! Seems I asked a really banal question lol

Answer (score 0):

A fundamental tool in playing with complex numbers is the complex conjugate.

Every non-real number $a+bi$ has a conjugate $a-bi$.

Try multiplying $a+bi$ by $a-bi$, remembering that $i^2 = -1$. What do you find?

This means that instead of "dividing" both sides of an equation by a complex number, we can multiply both sides by its conjugate and simplify. Give it a go and see if it helps.

Comment: Of course to be technically accurate, a real number also has a complex conjugate, which is itself.